# Wordpress Footer for mobile

Tags: php, html, wordpress, footer

im having a weird issue with my wordpress page:

http://test.costa.io/?page_id=28

The issue is when using the FullPageWidth, since in the homepage (http://test.costa.io/) the footer work as intended but in this one when the size is<728 the footer doesnt work properly.

I tried to delete all my media queries but still doing the same, also I tried changing all my code over and over but I cant find the solution.

Any help would be really nice.

Thanks

Comment: What is it exactly that is not working with the footer?

Comment: when you check it with a mobile, it didnt use the 100% width

Comment: In fact if u use the developers tool in chrome and put a mobile resolution u can see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this declared in your css :

```
#content2 #intro_seccion {
    width: 47.0625em;
    ...
```

Set it to `width: 100%;` for fullwidth.